# Cypress: Get an array of webelements

Tags: typescript, cypress

This might be a simple question, or something that cannot be done. But I find Cypress help on the net to be a bit "behind" compared to Selenium resources. Furthermore, being a Java programmer, I'm struggling a bit to come to terms with what I can and cannot do in TypeScript (as well as in Cypress compared to Selenium).

Is it at all possible, in Cypress (and TypeScript) to get an array of WebElements from code like this?

```
<div id="row-123">
   <span id="comment">
   <button id="purge>
   <input id="comment">
</div>
<div id="row-456">
   <span id="comment">
   <button id="purge>
   <input id="comment">
</div>
<div id="row-789">
   <span id="comment">
   <button id="purge>
   <input id="comment">
</div>
```

I'm trying with this:

```
var rows = Array(cy.get('*[id^="row"]'));
```

But when I try asserting the length of the rows[] array, it claims to be 1 instead of 3. So it doesn't work like I thought it would.

In Java and Selenium, I'd do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.id("^row"));
```

Then I could use for instance Stream() to parse each element into a class which then accessed the (sub)elements inside that. And so on. But I find this difficult to do in Cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) to iterate through an array like structure (arrays or objects with a length property).

```
let idArray = []
cy.get('*[id^="row"]').each(($el, index, $lis) => {
    //Find element based on InnerText
    if ($el.text() == 'text') {
        //Do something  
    }
    //Find element based on index position
    if (index == 1) {
        //Do something
    }
    //Save the id in the idArray
    cy.wrap($el).invoke('attr', 'id').then((val) => {
        idArray.push(val);
    })
}).then(($lis) => {
    expect($lis).to.have.length(3)
})
```

As per the discussion, a way to iterate over multiple tr's and td's and find the desired element based on innerText and then take some actions:

```
cy.get('tr').each(($el, index, $lis) => {
    cy.get('td').each(($el) => {
        if ($el.text() == 'text') {
            cy.log('Element found')
            return
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But isn't it possible to create an array and then access one of the elements in the array?

Comment: What values do you want to save in the array. Is it the Id ?

Comment: Well, in Java/Selenium I would create a class representing each row in the array. The rows would have elements like buttons, text fields etc., and the class would have methods for accessing those. That would make it easy, for instance, to use Stream() to access an element in a row with a specific title. If the rows represent persons, I could filter out the row for "Adam Brown" and then check his birth date, for instance.

Comment: Of course, each row doesn't have to be parsed into a class. It could just be the row and the elements inside it, and then I could find the specific element for a particular row.

Comment: I have updated the code. Within each you can find element based on the position or with inner text or if you want to save some values in an array and use it later, you can do that as well.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I access the elements in the array? Trying to access it by index results in IntelliJ complaining that "Variable 'idArray' implicitly has an 'any[]' type"

Comment: In the idArray we are storing the the id attribute only.

Comment: Yes, I see that, and I think I get how. But how to access it? Most operations operations seems to yield the same error. Also, I need to get to the web elements INSIDE the rows, not just the rows themselves. (Also, I've updated the example code to perhaps clarify a bit.)

Comment: That is, there are several other elements in the rows, with their own selectors that I need to access. Checking the values, clicking etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225730/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-hfrav).

Comment: Seems like the original question was still not answered.  **Can I just get a gosh dang array or not?**